# The task is to convert strings to floats, but my files are still strings. Why?

Tags: python-3.x

Here I'm trying to convert few numbers inside a list read from a file into float format, but my output comes still as a string format. Where is the problem?

```
table = [] 
fileName = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
readFile = open(fileName)
lines = readFile.readlines() 
    
for line in lines: 
    line = line.split()
    for item in line: 
        item = float(item)
    table.append(item)

print(table)
```

**Here is a screenshot of my code :**

[image: snapshot of code]

Comment: Welcome to SO but where is your code?

Comment: Please paste your code as (formatted) text in the question, not as an image

Comment: But I can easily see your issue is just a misuse of variable name `table.append(line)` should be `table.append(item)`, and it should be indented one more level.

Comment: Intend table.append(item) on the same level as item = float(item)

Comment: (@cwhisperer: *indent* rather than `Intend`)

Comment: Note that the code in the question deviates from the one in the raster rendition.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

You should append the item that is a float(stored in the variable Item) and not the string version(stored in the variable line) inside the loop so each item is added as the loop iterates through the items.I also use the `split()` function to add every three numbers into another nested list

**Here is the fixed code:**

```
table = []
readFile = open(filename)
lines = readFile.readlines()
for i  in lines:
    for line in i.split():
        items = float(lines)
        table = [[items]]

print(table)
```

**OR:**

```
readFile = open(filename)
lines = readFile.readlines()
table=[([items] for line in i.split) for i in lines]

print(table)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2.0,7.0,6.0],[9.0,5.0,1.0],[4.0,3.0,8.0]]
```